# C/C++ Linux Запуск програмы из контекста другой програмы без копрования стека, списка файлов и прочего

Tags: c++, linux, c

Предположим что существуют два независимых приложения A и B. Каждое из приложений имеет свою сферу применения и задачи. Они могут запускаться пользователем как самостоятельные приложения. В процессе работы каждое из приложений может иметь открытыми тысячи файлов и хранить в ОЗУ гигабайты данных. В качестве фичи каждое из приложений может запускать второе приложение отдельным процессом. При этом сценарий запуска A->B->A->B->A->B->... не запрещен.

fork() и exec() как мне кажется в данном примере не подходят, тк будут крайне медленны и ресурсозатратны; к тому же дочернему процессу совершенно не нужен доступ к данным от родителя.

Есть ли какой то системный вызов способный создать новый процесс как "чистый" запуск?

Comment: так копирования нет, там COW, плюс ко всему, вся система на этом построена.  Вы боитесь сожрать всю память?

Comment: COW это всё таки оптимизация процесса отпочкования. В момент создания fork`a увеличение памяти не произойдёт, но с течением времени родитель неизбежно будет дёргать память, а следовательно рано или поздно произойдёт её увеличение x2, в то время как потомок этой информацией пользоваться не будет никогда, а мы получим просто бессмысленно занятые ресурсы

Comment: На самом деле копируется не память, а только таблицы, но есть ещё vfork, который копирует ещё меньше. Мне кажется, Вы явно перегибаете в своих описаниях. Если бы все так было, тогда линукс системы давно бы уходили в недостаток памяти. А этого почему то не наблюдается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У дочернего процесса не будет доступа к данным (памяти) родителя, так как после execve создается новое адресное пространство. Стек у каждого нового потока выполнения будет свой в любом случае. А вот проблема утечки ресурсов из-за копирования таблицы файловых дескрипторов весьма актуальна. Многие программы и библиотеки откровенно забивают на использование флага `FD_CLOEXEC` для файлов. Соответственно запуск таких программ по образу  A->B->A->B->A->B->... неминуемо ведет к исчерпанию дескрипторов либо непреднамеренному удержанию файлов в открытом состоянии. Чтобы этого избежать необходимо озадачиваться легковесным процессом-супервайзером (привет, Erlang), который бы занимался именно запуском A и B, гарантированно не передавая в новые процессы нежелательных файловых дескрипторов.

Comment: боюсь, что автор вопроса не дойдет до того, что у него утекут все дескрипторы. Скорее всего он прочитал на каком то левом развлекательном сайте очередную страшилку или неверно понял сарказм старшего колеги.

Comment: @KoVadim А проблема может проявиться задолго до исчерпания доступных файловых дескрипторов, например когда после удаления файла он по-прежнему занимает место на диске, так как где-то продолжает висеть открытый дескриптор.

Comment: Что ж, я действительно не часто имею дело с Linux, поэтому могу неправильно понимать какие-то вещи либо не знать о них. Как например я не знал что **execve** не возвращает управление вызывающей программе, но мне не до конца понятен смысл определение о том что стек перезаписывается вызываемой программой. Означает ли это что стек вызывающей программы освобождается? Или только то что стек вызываемой программы располагаются в том же адресном пространстве, а старые ресурсы всё так же остаются выделенными в памяти и являются зарезервированными?

Comment: у каждого приложения свой стек. Никто просто так не лазит в чужое адресное пространство. В целом, Вы пишите приложения, закрывайте аккуратно за собой ресурсы, и все будет хорошо.

Comment: @Edglz После execve новая программа выполняется в новом адресном пространстве, с новым стеком, и ничего больше не знает об адресном пространстве и стеке вызывающей программы, которая продолжает жить сама по себе. Изменения в памяти, возникшие после вызова fork и до вызова еxecve в отпочковавшемся процессе, теряются. А родительский процесс об этих изменениях, даже если они были, вообще не знает.

Comment: По поводу флага COE, то он не совсем подходит, тк вполне допустимо что внутри приложений могут существовать иные вызовы exec() для  которых не стоит закрывать файлы.

Что до легковесного процесса-супервайзера, у меня была мысль решить эту проблему архитектурно с помощью такого отдельного приложения, с которым можно было общаться через FIFO, а тот в свою очередь уже запускал внутри себя fork() и exec() нужной программы. Но это очень похоже на велосипед, неужели в Linux нет готового диспечера который просто запускал бы приложения без лишних данных?

Comment: По-моему там вообще нет ничего готового...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь